# Using eval() and base64_decode() to obfuscate code - not working within a function?

Tags: php, base64, eval

In short, I'm building a self hosted application, and to create a basic level deterrent that'll stop those who have a small knowledge of development (i.e. my target market) from removing call backs, I've decided to use `eval()` and `base64_decode()` in order to obfuscate and execute a couple of lines of code - specifically those that deal with validating the users license key.

The problem I've run into however is that it seems that I can't run `eval(base64_decode(..));` within a function.

**For example, this works fine:**

```
eval(base64_decode('c2Vzc2lvbl9uYW1lKCJfaW5zdCIpOyBzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXJ0KCk7ICRfU0VTU0lPTlsna2V5J10gPSB0cnVlOyBlY2hvICI8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHRcIj53aW5kb3cubG9jYXRpb24gPSAnL2luc3QvYWRtaW4vc2V0dGluZ3MnPC9zY3JpcHQ+Ijs=');
```

executing the following,

```
session_name("_inst");
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = true;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location = '/inst/admin/settings'</script>";
```

**But this on the other hand, fails:**

```
function escapeOut() {
eval(base64_decode('c2Vzc2lvbl9uYW1lKCJfaW5zdCIpOyBzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXJ0KCk7ICRfU0VTU0lPTlsna2V5J10gPSB0cnVlOyAkZXNjYXBlID0gICI8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHRcIj53aW5kb3cubG9jYXRpb24gPSAnL2luc3QvYWRtaW4vc2V0dGluZ3MnPC9zY3JpcHQ+IjsgcmV0dXJuICRlc2NhcGU7'));
}

echo escapeOut();
```

it should execute the following,

```
session_name("_inst");
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = true;
$escape = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location = '/inst/admin/settings'</script>";
return $escape;
```

At first I wasn't returning `$escape`, but after realizing and rectifying that issue, I'm stumped. It's probably something pretty simple, but I'm pretty stumped.

Any answers as to why this doesn't work/what I can do to make it work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you obfuscate code this way?

Comment: Well, I can't think of a more effective way to do so - Zend Guard is out of the question because of it's expensiveness, and ionCube also because the lack of hosts that have it natively integrated, therefore the additional work load on the user to request it to be installed and edit php.ini.

Comment: This isn't even an effective method of obfuscating your code, though. It's trivial to reverse.

Comment: I haven't thought this all the way through, I'm just thinking of it as I go along really. I've converted `eval()` and `base64_decode()` to functions with random names, and I'll probably throw some more base 64 encoded strings within the original code.

Comment: Your obfuscation just makes things more complicated _for you_ , not for the person who wants to reverse your code. base64_decode() and all is there again. You should stop thinking about obfuscating and start reading about licences :)

Comment: But those who would seek to actually remove the callbacks are the ones who wouldn't care about licensing agreements anyway. I have automatic placement in a "no share" list on one of the largest software pirating sites as I know users there, so a large portion of the potential wranglers are solved anyway, this is for the few left over, who know enough PHP to edit the session variable check in my `header.php` file, but not enough to get around multiple set of encoding (encoded strings within encoded strings), obfuscated variable/function names etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having `return` in your `eval()` statement will return *from* eval, not from the outer function.

i think you need something like this:

```
function escapeOut(){
    return eval(base64_decode('c2Vzc2lvbl9uYW1lKCJfaW5zdCIpOyBzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXJ0KCk7ICRfU0VTU0lPTlsna2V5J10gPSB0cnVlOyAkZXNjYXBlID0gICI8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHRcIj53aW5kb3cubG9jYXRpb24gPSAnL2luc3QvYWRtaW4vc2V0dGluZ3MnPC9zY3JpcHQ+IjsgcmV0dXJuICRlc2NhcGU7'));
}

echo escapeOut();
```

also, keep in mind it's trivial to `echo base64_decode('c2Vzc2lvbl9uYW1lKCJfaW5zdCIp...`